# GoogleSheets onEdit() rounddown the number

Tags: google-apps-script

What scripts should I use to rounddown the input number to the nearest multiple of 4, on a specific cell (N30). I've tried using this code, but it doesn't works:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange().getActiveCell("N30");
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveCell(). Math.Mround("N30,4");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 function onEdit() 
 {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var num= sheet.getRange("N30").getValue();

  if((num%4)>2)
  {
    num = ((Math.floor((num/4))) + 1)*4;
  }
  else
  {
    num = Math.floor((num/4))*4;
  }

  sheet.getRange("N30").setValue(num);
 }
```

Comment: Happy to help. :)